# When it says put crossdomain.xml in the root where would that be on IIS?

Tags: iis, flash, crossdomain.xml

Would it be wwwroot, C, the root virtual directory where the assets are hosted, or the same folder that the assets are in?

Meaning if I have a virtual directory 'virdir' with a sub directory 'swf', which is really like C:\somedir\assets\swf\, where would the crossdomain.xml need to go so that my swf app on a different server can access the swfs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to be able to access it as http://yoursite.com/crossdomain.xml so where would you put it to do that?

As a rule of thumb I put it next to my index.html for the site.

Comment: Is that in the IIS virtual directory for the website?

Answer (score 2):

wwwroot will likely work for you.