# getting xml data via ajax crosss domain request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to access an xml file suing jquery and ajax call. I found that that cross domain request are not allowed unless you do some config changes on the web server.

I am doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#div1").jstree({

    "xml_data": {

        "ajax": {
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'xml', 
            url: "http://192.168.101.1/img/tree.xml"
```

I have modified iis web.config file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Recycled IIs but I still cannot access that xml file. Any ideas how I can tackle this issue?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?  And, are you seeing the request being made by your client (e.g. you see the request being sent in Fiddler, FireBug, Chrome Tools, etc.)?

Comment: I dont see any errors from the IIS log. I cannot tell a request is being made since there is no entry in the iis event viewer.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? I remember there being an issue with making CORS requests in IE, it required additional code.

Comment: Also, remove `crossDomain: true,` it isn't relevant to what you are doing. That option is meant for forcing jQuery to treat a local request as a crossDomian quest. You aren't making a local request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send ajax request to your app, and get this xml from app to not bother with cross-domains calls.

Comment: yes, thank you. Ive created a server side script and calling that script within my jquery. Awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set [your crossdomain.xml](https://serverfault.com/questions/303808/how-do-you-set-up-the-crossdomain-xml-for-site-whose-url-is-the-machine-name) in the server.

Example to put on root of the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Also worth reading where [to place the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213389/when-it-says-put-crossdomain-xml-in-the-root-where-would-that-be-on-iis).